# Number of lineary independent solutions of Homogenous nth Order Linear Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

On Calculus I test theory, I had question for the number of lineary independent solutions of linear homogenous differential equation of nth order $ L_n[y] = 0$.

As far as I know there always exist fundamental set of solution, and fundamental solution is the set of n lineary independent solution of equation:
$$ L_n[y]= y^{(n)} + a_1(x)y^{(n-1)}+...+ a_n(x)y = 0$$

According to my workbook, there can be less than n lineary independent solutions, but not more than n lineary independent solution, so how could this be explained?

Comment: That is not different than for any number of linear independent vectors in a vector space of dimension $n$. The solution space is of dimension $n$.

Comment: For each $0\leqslant k\leqslant n-1$, consider $y_k$ the solution with initial condition $y_k^{(k)}(0)=1$ and $y_k^{(i)}(0)=0$ for every $0\leqslant i\leqslant n-1$, $i\ne k$. Then $(y_0,y_1,\ldots,y_{n-1})$ is a linearly independent set of solutions of size $n$, and a minute of thought allows to convince oneself this is a *basis* of the space of solutions, hence the space of solutions has dimension $n$, always. Thus, I fail to understand the assertion from your workbook.